# Linq Where fails when trying to check a range

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

When trying to check if a variable is within a range the code does not work.

This is a project in Radzen, Linq is interacting with a mysql database

This does not work:

```cs
var QuantQ = dbContext.CnpjCnaes.Where(x => x.CAPITAL_SOCIAL < CapMaximo && x.CAPITAL_SOCIAL > CapMinimo && x.CNAE_FISCAL == Parametros[4] && x.COD_MUNICIPIO == CidadeQ.ToArray()[0].COD_MUNICIPIO.ToString());
```

But this does:

```cs
var QuantQ = dbContext.CnpjCnaes.Where(x => x.CAPITAL_SOCIAL < CapMaximo &&  x.CNAE_FISCAL == Parametros[4] && x.COD_MUNICIPIO == CidadeQ.ToArray()[0].COD_MUNICIPIO.ToString());
```

Well I expected to get a range between CapMinimo and CapMaximo, but it seems that when I try to check a range it always fails.

Comment: What are your values for CapMaximo and CapMinimo? Are you sure data actually exists for those ranges? Are you getting an exception, or no results?

Comment: I am getting an exception. And yes I do get data whenever I do the second one. The valus for CapMaximo and CapMinimo work, because whenever I do only half of the check of the range like (> CapMinimo) it works.

Comment: what exception are you getting?

Comment: Try adding parenthesis : (x.CAPITAL_SOCIAL < CapMaximo) && (x.CAPITAL_SOCIAL > CapMinimo)

Comment: I don't know what happened. I had this issue yesterday, left from work, come back today and it works...I didn't make any change.

Comment: Those `Parametros[4]` and `CidadeQ.ToArray()[0].COD_MUNICIPIO.ToString()` seem fairly constant. You may want to extract them to variables in advance, and use these variables in the linq expression. Remember, the linq lookups are actually treated as functions; they get called exactly as they are written, on every internal check the `Where` function performs, meaning it has to do these lookup and convert operations on your arrays and lists every single time.

Comment: Hi @LeviBarrocas, welcome to SO. You mention you get an exception but you haven't posted any exception information. Please post the entire exception stack so we can help you.

Comment: @Nyerguds That isn't true for LINQ to SQL or EF.

Comment: @NetMage How so? It is true for the `x => f(x)` construct in general. Even if it isn't though, that looks pretty polluted. For all we know his exception may be in those array lookups, and not in the `Where`. Better to extract them anyway.

Comment: i assume CAPITAL_SOCIAL is NOT NULLABLE field...

Comment: @Nyerguds I don't think you understand how LINQ to SQL/EF works. LINQ expression trees are translated to SQL and sent to the database engine to be processed. Expressions that are client side are evaluated once to create a constant that will be transmitted to the server as a parameter to the SQL query e.g. the entire `Where` will execute server-side, translated and sent once to return all the rows that pass.